# Pytorch inputs for nn.CrossEntropyLoss()

Tags: pytorch, logistic-regression

I am trying to perform a Logistic Regression in PyTorch on a simple 0,1 labelled dataset. The criterion or loss is defined as: `criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()`. The model is: `model = LogisticRegression(1,2)`

I have a data point which is a pair: `dat = (-3.5, 0)`, the first element is the datapoint and the second is the corresponding label.
Then I convert the first element of the input to a tensor: `tensor_input = torch.Tensor([dat[0]])`.
Then I apply the model to the tensor_input: `outputs = model(tensor_input)`.
Then I convert the label to a tensor: `tensor_label = torch.Tensor([dat[1]])`.
Now, when I try to do this, the thing breaks: `loss = criterion(outputs, tensor_label)`. It gives and error: `RuntimeError: Dimension out of range (expected to be in range of [-1, 0], but got 1)`

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn

class LogisticRegression(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_size, num_classes):
        super(LogisticRegression, self).__init__()
        self.linear = nn.Linear(input_size, num_classes) 

    def forward(self, x):
        out = self.linear(x)
        return out

model = LogisticRegression(1,2)
criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
dat = (-3.5,0)
tensor_input = torch.Tensor([dat[0]])
outputs = binary_model(tensor_input)
tensor_label = torch.Tensor([dat[1]])
loss = criterion(outputs, tensor_label)
```

I can't for the life of me figure it out.

Comment: Just on a side note: You are defining only `model` in your sample code, but you are later using `binary_model` for the forward pass. Might just be a typo, but I don't know your code.

Answer (score 10):

For the most part, the PyTorch documentation does an amazing job to explain the different functions; they usually do include expected input dimensions, as well as some simple examples.
You can find the description for `nn.CrossEntropyLoss()` [here](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#crossentropyloss).

To walk through your specific example, let us start by looking at the expected input dimension:

> Input: (N,C) where C = number of classes. [...]

To add to this, *N* generally refers to the batch size (number of samples). To compare this to what you currently have:

```
outputs.shape
>>> torch.Size([2])
```

I.e. currently we only have an input dimension of `(2,)`, and not `(1,2)`, as is expected by PyTorch. We can alleviate this by adding a "fake" dimension to our current tensor, by simply using `.unsqueeze()` like so:

```
outputs = binary_model(tensor_input).unsqueeze(dim=0)
outputs.shape
>>> torch.Size([1,2])
```

Now that we got that, let us look at the expected input for the targets:

> Target: (N) [...]

So we already got the right shape for this. If we try this, though, we will still encounter an error, though:

```
RuntimeError: Expected object of scalar type Long but got scalar type Float 
              for argument #2 'target'.
```

Again, the error message is rather expressive. The problem here is that PyTorch tensors (by default) are interpreted as `torch.FloatTensors`, but the input should be integers (or `Long`) instead. We can simply do this by specifying the exact type during tensor creations:

```
tensor_label = torch.LongTensor([dat[1]])
```

I'm using PyTorch 1.0 under Linux fyi.

Answer (score 2):

To perform a Logistic Regression in PyTorch you need 3 things:

- Labels(targets) encoded as 0 or 1;
- Sigmoid activation on last layer, so the num of outputs will be 1;
- Binary Cross Entropy as Loss function.

Here is minimal example:

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn


class LogisticRegression(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, n_inputs, n_outputs):
        super(LogisticRegression, self).__init__()
        self.linear = nn.Linear(n_inputs, n_outputs)
        self.sigmoid = nn.Sigmoid()


    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.linear(x)
        return self.sigmoid(x)


# Init your model
# Attention!!! your num_output will be 1, because logistic function returns one value in range (0, 1) 
model = LogisticRegression(n_inputs=1, n_outputs=1)
# Define Binary Cross Entropy Loss:
criterion = nn.BCELoss()

# dummy data
data = (42.0, 0)
tensor_input = torch.Tensor([data[0]])
tensor_label = torch.Tensor([data[1]])

outputs = model(tensor_input)

loss = criterion(outputs, tensor_label)

print(loss.item())
```

Comment: I partially disagree with this answer. Since the question is specifically about `nn.CrossEntropyLoss()`, and not `nn.BCELoss()`, it's slightly off, even though it correctly solves the problem of LogisticRegression, as you mention. Furthermore, though, `nn.Sigmoid() wil apply *element-wise*, i.e. the output is the same shape as the input; you have to make sure that there is only one element going into this yourself.